# Why does layerView as returned by view.whenLayerView not have a watch method in it?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-react

It seems to me that the `layerView` variable used as in this line:

```js
view.whenLayerView(layer).then((layerView) => {
```

does not have the `watch` property so the zooming-to-Romania functionality does not work in my code.

Here is a code sandbox you can test and fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-kirch-nm0lm?file=/src/App.js (I think it is best viewed and edited in Chromium).

We are using the latest version of `esri-loader`.

I have read some documentation pages such as [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-core-Accessor.html#watch) but it is not of much help.

The main piece of code is this:

```js
/**
 * When the layer view updates, zoom onto it.
 */
function zoomOnUpdate(layerView, view) {
  // if (typeof layerView.watch !== "function") {
  //   // debugger;
  //   console.log("error", layerView);
  //   return;
  // }

  console.log("dir", Object.keys(layerView));
  const handler = layerView.watch("updating", (val) => {
    // if the component is not being updated, do nothing
    // if (!val) return;

    // zoom onto it
    layerView.queryExtent().then((results) => {
      // here the results can be like this:
      // { count: 0, extent: null }
      // (I don't know why)
      console.log("RESULTS", results);
      view.goTo(results.extent);
    });
  });

  handlers.push(handler);
}
```

The output of the first `console.log` is this:

```js
dir 
["_emitter", "_promiseProps", "lastUpdateId", "refreshDebounced", "_effect", "_viewStateId", "_visibilityOverrides", "_highlightIds", "doRefresh", "_onRenderingConfigChange", "_updateHighlight"]
```

I also logged the `layerView.prototype` and `layerView.__prototype__` and the browser told me that they are null or undefined, although I did not verify this in all situations.

The `zoomOnUpdate` function is used in a single place, like this:

```js
view.whenLayerView(layer).then((layerView) => {
  zoomOnUpdate(layerView, view);
  layerView.filter = { where: "Country_co = 'RO'  AND Source = 'RO' " };

  // setModules({ ...modules });
  // setModulesAreLoading(false);
});
```

The URL of the layer is this: https://trial.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/rest/services/BISE/NUTS0_Marine/MapServer/0.

If this question is better suited for StackOverflow please forgive me and move it where it is most likely answered.